# Size of $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains $p+1$ points

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory, number-theory

I am struggling to prove this claim:

I proved that the map $x\mapsto x^3+1$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to itself if we have that $p\equiv 2\bmod{3}$. We have to use this fact to prove that the elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains precisely $p+1$ points.

I don't understand how many points will be on the curve. For each value of $x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ we will get a distinct result after computing $x^3+1$. But how does that tell me how many points will be on the curve?

For each point it can be paired with either two or zero $y$ values, right? But I don't know how many squares there are that are less than $p$.

I ask either for help explaining this, or ideally resources I could use to understand the theory behind this so that I can solve it myself.

Comment: _"squares there are that are less than $p$"_ is immaterial, and not defined when working in the field modulo $p$, as we are. The right line of reasoning is: for each $y$ in this field, how many $x$ in this field are there such that $(x,y)$ is the coordinates of a point on the curve? Are these points distinct? Are there other points that we need to count?

Comment: @fgrieu You can also do it the other way, for every $x$, count the $y$s, as in the other answer. It's a bit messier however since you have to case-distinguish based on whether $x^3+1$ is a quadratic residue or non-residue or zero (and know a bit about residuosity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every $y \in \mathbf F_p$, there is a unique $x \in \mathbf F_p$ such that $(x,y)$ is on the curve, namely $x = \phi^{-1}(y^2)$, where $\phi : x \mapsto x^3+1$. Adding the point at infinity, that gives $p+1$ points.

Comment: So, for each $y\in\mathbb{F}_p$ we have that $y^2$ is some other value in the same field. And since our map $\phi$ is bijective, we will find a unique $x$ that it can be paired with so that it lies on our elliptic curve. And that gives us $p$ points, then we add the point at infinity. I understand you correvctly, right? But what about $-y$, won't we have that $(x,-y)$ is on the curve for every $(x,y)$? Won't that give us $2p+1$ points?

Comment: @Sandstar No because $y$ and $-y$ are different values, so the fact that they are paired with the same $x$ is irrelevant to the argument.

Comment: I think I get you. Do we have that $(x,y) = -(x,-y)$? And so for each negative value of $y$, we will find that it is actually equivalent to some other $y'$?

Comment: Yes, if $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$ are both on the curve, then they are opposite (w.r.t. the curve group operation) since the line through them is vertical.

Comment: By the way, there are no "negative" values in finite fields.

Comment: Riiight, I think that is a point of confusion I had. Because $(x,y)$ is on the curve, and so obviously $(x,-y)$ is also on the curve. I thought that meant an additional point on the curve, but in $\mathbb{F}_p -y$ is just another value, say $y'\in\mathbb{F}_p$. So it's  not another point, it's one we already accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

With the bijection, you proved that for every $x$ there is a unique $x^3+1$. Now, for modulo an odd prime number $p$  the number of QR (quadratic residue) is $(p + 1)/2$ by [Euler's criterion](http://Euler's%20criterion).

Therefore these are the solutions for $y^2$s for your EC. For every $y$, $-y$ is going to satisfies the equation i.e. if $(x,y)$ is a point on the curve than $(x,-y)$ is also a point on the curve except $y=0$ for which there is only one. This makes $(p+1)/2-1 = p$ points and with the addition of $\mathcal{O}$-the point on the infinity, the number of points will make $p+1$

---

Below is the SageMath code for the test.

```
F = GF(17)
E = EllipticCurve(F,[0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
E.cardinality()

for uInt in range(0, 17):
         u = F(uInt)
         v2 = u^3 + 1
         if not v2.is_square():
           continue
         v = v2.sqrt()
         point = E(u, v)
         pointOrder = point.order()
         print( point, pointOrder)
         print( -point, pointOrder)

Q = quadratic_residues(17)
Q
```

```
With the output

((0 : 1 : 1), 3)
((0 : 16 : 1), 3)
((1 : 6 : 1), 9)
((1 : 11 : 1), 9)
((2 : 3 : 1), 6)
((2 : 14 : 1), 6)
((6 : 8 : 1), 18)
((6 : 9 : 1), 18)
((7 : 2 : 1), 9)
((7 : 15 : 1), 9)
((9 : 4 : 1), 18)
((9 : 13 : 1), 18)
((10 : 7 : 1), 18)
((10 : 10 : 1), 18)
((14 : 5 : 1), 9)
((14 : 12 : 1), 9)
((16 : 0 : 1), 2)         ---> -y = y => y=0
((16 : 0 : 1), 2)         --->
[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16]
```

Comment: What if $y = 0$?

Comment: @fkraiem corrected, thanks.